# django south postgresql foreign key constraint require a row of id zero?

Tags: database, django, postgresql, foreign-keys, django-south

I am using Django with South as the data migration tool for a Postgresql database.

What I have met is such a situation: if I add a field in a model which is a foreign key related with another model. I generate the migration file with

`./manage.py schemamigration users --auto`

but an error occurred if trying to

`./manage.py migrate users 00xx`

with the files generated.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "users_userlikemessage" violates foreign key constraint "message_id_refs_id_57ff7c7c"

DETAIL:  Key (message_id)=(0) is not present in table "message_article".
```

What I have done to solve the problem is just go to the last row of the `message_artile` model from pdAdmin tool and change the id of the row to `0`, and re-run the migrate command.

Though this solved the migration problem, but I am not able to change that `0` id back to what it was, due to that existing FK constraint.

So, my questions are:

1. What is the reason that `0` valued pk must exist before the FK constraint can be established?
2. Is there a better way to solve this?
3. Does this existing FK constraint have a side effect to future use of the database?
4. Does it make sense to have a `0` valued pk in Postgresql database?

Comment: Why would you add a FK constraint if you dont allow the DBMS to enforce it? Makes no sense. (BTW: 0 != NULL)

Comment: ./manage.py schemamigration --auto user